# How can I always have the node title display on top of a background image?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, blocks

With Drupal 8, the page title is available through a block now. We have several content types where we have an Image field (field_image) and we constantly have to write templates per content type to place the title on top of the image.

It would be nice if we could use the view modes of each content type or some module to do this. Basically, something that does "take the field image, set it as a background, and place the title on top."

Is there a better way to do this programmatically as we cannot find any other way to do this?

Comment: You can override node.twig.html and config hidden block title with contentent type.

Comment: I've made something like this with an override of node.twig.html (as @MrD say) and used the "twig_tweak" to load the block and "twig_field_value" to display the image as background. Hope it helps !

Comment: This can be done using Drupal Views module. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtV78ufp9Jw. There is also the [GD Header module](https://www.drupal.org/project/gd_header). "This module provides a block with the page title and a configurable image in the background".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several ways to solve this

### 1 make your own module

to do what you described

### 2 add theme templates

for each content type as you described

### 3 Use [background_image](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_image) module

The module is available for Drupal 8 promises to do just this (I meant to use it but have not actually)

According to the the project description provides a way to insert token values

> Token - Provides a way to view which tokens are available to use when
>   adding overlay text for a background image.

So you can probably use it with a field token to accomplish what you need

Answer (score 1):

[Background Images Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter) is another option for accomplishing this, especially when you might want different images on different pages.

> This module provides an image formatter that allows you to set an
>   image in background of a tag. The images are from a field of an entity
>   and not from a configuration page or a custom entity or something
>   else, so it's very easy to setup and manage.